# Node-js. Проблемка с эвентами

Tags: node.js, события

Пишу парсер на node.js, возникла проблемка с эвентами.
Как всегда ждать определённого эвента, даже если нет действий для выполнения?
То-бишь:
У меня вначале `MyEventEmmiter.on('event', (args)=>{/*код*/})`
За ним, при каком либо условии(пусть это будет `var r = 0 == 0`), стоит `emit`:
`var r = 0;if(r==0) MyEventEmmiter.emit(event, args);`
Но происходит выход из этого скрипта между `MyEventEmmiter.emit(...)` и `MyEventEmmiter.on(...)`, а я того не хочу.
Debug от VScode ничего не показал(просто после `emit` выход из скрипта).

Зарание спасибо.

Comment: 100% есть какой-нибудь способ решить Вашу задачу через специальные методы (в модуле process), но я о них не знаю. Зато знаю костыльный способ - ,установите  `setTimeout` на любое приемлемое для Вас время.

Comment: Увы, еслиб этот парсер был бы себе, я бы и закостылил, но этот парсер на заказ...